# Less opacity for element-part which is going outside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi please see my html code .

```js
$( function() {
   $( ".new-img" ).draggable();
});
```

```css
.all{
  background-color:blue;
}
.new-multiple{
  width:400px !important;
  height:400px !important;
  background:white;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow:visible;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="all">
  <div class="new-multiple">
    <div class="new-img">
      <img src="https://launchbit.com/carbon-i/6599-ToptalCarbon.jpg">
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vd11qyzv/23/

Here i want to reduce the opacity of image part which is going outside the div [not for full image opacity , but for the portion going outside the .new-multiple div].

Is it possible ? Please advice .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add an element with a high z-index in the Blue zone with opacity and the image will go under it like this :

**BUT** you will no more be able to dragg the image outside unless you change the z-index of the image after the drop.

```js
$( function() {
   $( ".new-img" ).draggable({
      start: function( event, ui ) { $(this).css('z-index','99');  },
      stop: function( event, ui ) {$(this).css('z-index','9999999');}
   });
});
```

```css
.all{
  background-color:blue;
  position:relative;
  width:500px;
}
.all:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 198px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 127, 0.68);
}
.new-multiple{
  width:300px !important;
  height:300px !important;
  background:white;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow:visible;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="all">
  <div class="new-multiple">
    <div class="new-img">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the image to be semi transparent, then i have updated your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/vd11qyzv/24/

HTML

```
<div class="all">
<div class="new-multiple">
    <div class="new-img">
    <img src="https://launchbit.com/carbon-i/6599-ToptalCarbon.jpg">
    <div><img src="https://launchbit.com/carbon-i/6599-ToptalCarbon.jpg"></div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.all{
    background-color:blue;
}
.new-multiple{
    width:400px !important;
    height:400px !important;
    background:white;
    border:2px solid red;
    overflow:visible;
}

.new-img  {
    display:inline-block;
}  
.new-img > img {
    opacity:0.5;
}

.new-img div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

JS

```
$( function() {
$( ".new-img" ).draggable({
    drag: function() {
            var left = $(this).position().left - $(".new-multiple").position().left;
        var width = $(this).outerWidth();
        var parentwidth = $(".new-multiple").outerWidth();
        var childwidth = parentwidth - (width + left);

        console.log(left, width, parentwidth)
        console.log(childwidth, width + childwidth);

        $('.new-img div').css({width: width + childwidth})
    }
});
});
```

Comment: please explain what you did

Comment: Can we do using only one img tag?

Comment: I cloned the image and set it to be the same position, I then set the original image to be 0.5 opacity. I then set the width of the parent of the secondary image to be (position left - width of the container). This hides part of the image, But it also means this only works  when dragging the image to the right. You would need to add in additional values for the other sides and corners.

Comment: And you can yes, you can set the background of the div or you can clone it with jQuery.